# Abbreviated notation for "elementwise vector variance"

Tags: notation

Suppose $X = (x_1, ..., x_N)$.
I would like to work with its "population variance" $s^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}$. Writing out this formula inside a longer expression would be distracting.

One way to write it is $s^2 = Var(\{x_i \mid i =1, \dots,N\})$, or even $s^2 = Var(X)$.

Unfortunately these two $Var(\bullet)$ seem to be invalid expressions, since in the first case $\bullet$ is a set rather than a random variable, and in the second case it is a vector.

Is there a way to abbreviate "elementwise vector variance"?

Comment: You are finding the covariance matrix?

Comment: @GNUSupporter nope, I want a single number.

Comment: I wouldn't see a problem with $\text{Var}(X)$ nor $\text{Var}_X$ nor $\sigma^2(X)$ nor $\sigma^2_X$ nor $s^2(X)$ nor $s^2_X$. For double safety, you can announce this notation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you, I just had to make sure. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Josef: wait to see if you don't get more authoritative answers.

Answer (score 0):

$s^2 = \frac{1}{N}{\lVert X - \bar{X} \rVert}^2$ is somewhat shorter, but it is still quite verbose and it may not be clear that $N$ is the dimension of $X$.